# What is the while loop equivalent to this for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to convert both the `for` loops in my code into `while` loops. Here is the code.

```
class CountryCatalogue:
    def __init__(self, countryFile):  # constructor method that takes name of file
        self.countryCat = []  # The instance variable country cat needed
        file = open(countryFile, "r")  # open and read the file
        for strip in file:
            strip = strip.strip()
            data = strip.split('|')  # Remove '|' in each line
            clean_data = Country(data[0], data[2], data[3], data[1])  # Create an object to country
            self.countryCat.append(clean_data)  # Append the item to the list
        file.close()  # Close the file

    def setPopulationOfCountry(self, country, population):
        for pop in range(len(self.countryCat)):  # iterate through countryCat
            if self.countryCat[pop].getName() == country.getName():
                self.countryCat[pop].setPopulation(population)  # updating data if needed
```

I tried to change the second for loop this way:

```
def setPopulationOfCountry(self, country, population):
    pop = 0
    while pop < (len(self.countryCat)):
        if self.countryCat[pop].getName() == country.getName():
            self.countryCat[pop].setPopulation(population)  # updating data if needed
            pop = pop + 1
```

But it didn't work and I wasn't sure about the first `for` Loop.

Comment: But _why_? Also, why isn't `countryCat` a dict keyed by country name so you could look them up by name _without_ a loop?

Comment: Because I showed my code to my friend and im scared he's gonna copy it so I want to change all my for loops to while loops. CountryCat isn't a dict keyed because the user enters the file before and it the program doesn't know which file will be entered to it just makes a empty list then fills it with the file data after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your while loop:

```
def setPopulationOfCountry(self, country, population):
    pop = 0
    while pop < (len(self.countryCat)):
        if self.countryCat[pop].getName() == country.getName():
            self.countryCat[pop].setPopulation(population)  # updating data if needed
            pop = pop + 1
```

you put the pop = pop + 1 in the if statement, get it out:

```
def setPopulationOfCountry(self, country, population):
    pop = 0
    while pop < (len(self.countryCat)):
        if self.countryCat[pop].getName() == country.getName():
            self.countryCat[pop].setPopulation(population)  # updating data if needed
        pop = pop + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't realize that. What do you think of the first for loop?

Comment: in the for loop, you go line by line?

Comment: how could I convert the first for loop the " for strip in file:" in my constructor method to a while loop. I have tried a few things but none of them are working.

Comment: I asked, the strip in the for loop is a line in the file?

Comment: no the strip is not in the file. I could have just used x instead

Comment: do you have any empty line in your file?

Comment: its just a for loop that strip each "|" in each line of the file selected. because the data points are each separated by these.

Comment: I am sorry if you can't answer clearly I cannot help you, I ask one last time, in your file, is there ANY empty line before the last line? (Yes/No)

Comment: My apologies. No.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found to change your file for loop to a while loop is to go through each line:

```
file = open(countryFile, "r")  # open and read the file
strip = file.readline()
while strip != "":
    strip = file.readline()
```

Comment: Here is how I changed my code. I get an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: class CountryCatalogue:
    def __init__(self, countryFile):  
        self.countryCat = []  # The instance variable country cat needed
        file = open(countryFile, "r")  # open and read the file
        strip = file.readline()
        while strip != "":
            strip = file.readline()
            data = strip.split('|')  # Remove '|' in each line
            clean_data = Country(data[0], data[2], data[3], data[1])  # Create an object to country
            self.countryCat.append(clean_data)  # Append the item to the list
        file.close()  # Close the file

Comment: the strip = file.readline() should be the very lash line inside the while loop, NOT the first one

Comment: its all messed up when I try to comment my code. could you show me what it would like with all the other stuff like "Country(data[0], data[2], data[3], data[1])" and "elf.countryCat.append(clean_data)". again thank you so much